# How to open, read multiple text files and bind all the texts read in only one file?

Tags: python, loops, directory

I have a program that asks the user to enter a directory containing n number of .txt files (texts). I want to open and read all the texts files of this directory entered by the user and, after that, put all the texts together in only one file sequentially...with the code below a get a error message below, which does not make sense because the file "Chapter22.txt" is in the Folder. Can anyone help understand what is going on?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/join_files.py", line 27, 
in <module>
    join_texts()
  File "/Users/nataliaresende/Dropbox/PYTHON/join_files.py", line 13, 
in join_texts
    with open(file) as b:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Chapter22.txt'
```

I've tried to loop in the entered directory opening and reading each of the files and appending them to a list. After that, use the ' '. join method to convert the texts appended to the list into a string. Is there an easier way to do that?

```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path

def join_texts():

    files_list=[]

    files_directory = Path(input('Enter the path of the files: '))


    for file in os.listdir(files_directory):
        with open(file) as b:
            f=b.read()
            files_list.append(f)



    joined_files=' '.join(files_list)

    print(joined_files)





join_texts()
```

The expected result would be a file containing all the texts from this directory together. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: What exactly don't work at all?

Comment: @MediaEU. I will edit my post with the error I get when I run the program.

Comment: @Prune, I've updated my question and the code. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @MediaEU,  I've edited the question to answer to your questions. I get a error message.

Comment: It's better, but not yet up to the guidelines.  We have no way to reproduce your directory structure to reproduce the problem.  What you've posted is simply a contradiction: the program says the file isn't there; you say it is.  You haven't traced the operation; we don't know what you've opened, what's in the list, how many previous files might have worked, etc.

Comment: (1) Your program hangs at the input line: we should not have to hand-enter anything to reproduce the problem.  Hard-code the path; give us the directory structure.  (2) We don't know what *you* received for your list of files.  (3) We don't know how many times the loop might have executed; the problem could be with the path, with the first file, or some anomaly with a later file.  (Z) In short, my vote to close still stands.